# Is it safe to override RLMObject -hash?

Tags: objective-c, hash, realm

I need a way to get the hash code of a `RLMObject`, but when I was inspecting the realm implementation and I found out that Realm (objective-c) uses the `primaryKey` on `RLMObjectBase`:

```
- (NSUInteger)hash {

    if (_objectSchema.primaryKeyProperty) {
        id primaryProperty = [self valueForKey:_objectSchema.primaryKeyProperty.name];

        // modify the hash of our primary key value to avoid potential (although unlikely) collisions
        return [primaryProperty hash] ^ 1;
    }
    else {
        return [super hash];
    }
}
```

I need something more *hashable* and that differs if the object properties.
My question is: can I safely override `-hash` method on my subclass without messing with any internal Realm mechanism?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Realm does not use `-[RLMObject hash]` internally, so it does not impose any restrictions on you overriding it.

The only requirement is the usual Foundation one that any objects which `-isEqual:` returns `YES` for must also have the same result from `-hash`, and the hash can't change after the object has been added to a Foundation collection. Realm hashes the primary key because that's the only immutable thing identifying the object it has access to.